# password textfield on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to use password styled textfield in iPhone (when typing, only: "*"'s will apper...).

The problem:
When i check the "secure" checkbox nothing happens - I still see the actual chars I'm typing....

What am I missing?

Comment: This might be the correct behavior for password textfields on iphone.  
The plaintext letter appears and after 2 seconds or when you've typed the next letter it is converted into a •

Comment: Are you **sure** nothing happens and you see your entire password in plain text?

Comment: Tnx for the replies. YES - I'm sure i still see plaintext and not: "*"'s... I'm using the Interface Builder, BTW.

Comment: My bad. u all were right - it's working! (I built another project... sry).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UITextField shows the last typed character as the original character (for around 1 sec), and the other characters will be shown as ****. This is the default behavior of iOS

Comment: Is there any way to make it not to show that last char at all, and replace it with a * as soon as you typed it?